# Strongly continuous unitary representation

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define the unitary operators $U_x$ and $V_y$ on $H$ by

$U_x(f)(t)=f(t-x)$ and $V_y(f)(t)=e^{-i\lambda\langle y|t\rangle}f(t)$.
I want to prove that both these unitary representations are strongly continuous. That is I need to prove that for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the map $x \mapsto U_x(f)$ and the map $y \mapsto V_y(f)$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show $U_x(f)$ is continuous at $x=0$, i.e. we want to show

\begin{align}
\lim_{|x|\rightarrow 0}\|U_x(f)-f\|_{L^2}^2 = \lim_{|x|\rightarrow 0}\int dy\ |f(x-y)-f(y)|^2 =0.
\end{align}

By density argument, it suffices to assume $f$ is smooth with compact support. Since 
\begin{align}
\lim_{|x|\rightarrow 0}(f(x-y)-f(y)) = 0
\end{align} 
for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $|f(x-y)-f(y)|\leq 3|f(y)|$ then by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem you are done.  The other operator is similar (after you apply Plancherel).

**Additional:** Observe
\begin{align}
\widehat{V_y(f)} =&\ \int dx\  e^{-ix\cdot\xi} V_y(f) = \int dx\ e^{-ix\cdot\xi}e^{-i\lambda x\cdot y}f(x)\\
=&\ \int dx\ e^{-ix\cdot(\xi+\lambda y)}f(x) = \hat f (\xi+\lambda y).
\end{align}

Comment: How the inequality $|f(x-y)-f( y)|  \leq 3|f( y)|$?

Comment: If you assume $|x|\le 1$ then you can obtain a $L^\infty$ bound since $f$ is compactly supported. I was being very loose with my bounds.

Comment: I was sloppy with the details, but the idea is clear.

Comment: Can you give me a little more details for the function $y \mapsto V_y(f)$?

Comment: Compute the Fourier transform of $V_y(f)$.

Comment: I do not know much about Fourier transforms. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Thank you so much